# android: how should i indicate that a "search string" is in play and is filtering the results

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm building an android app - where the user can enter a text query (similar to a search query on ebay) in a search dialog.

after the search is launched the search dialog disappears- but i still want to indicate to the users - that the list they are watching is still filtered-  according to the search string.  and I want to let the users cancel the query filter, if they see fit.

what is a good approach to doing that ? what component(s) should i use ?

thanks

Comment: This is really broad, and will probably be closed, but I've used a number of things. The most popular I've used includes changing the header from "Results" to "Filtered Results" or "My List of Stuff" to "My Filtered List of Stuff"

Comment: thanks.
and what was you approach  for allowing the user to remove the filter ?

Comment: Depends on the application and amount of real estate I have on the screen. I've used a "Clear All Filters" link under or near the header. I've also used a filter icon that a user could tap to show the search view and from there clear or modify it. On Android and iOS specifically I have used the back button to reset the list filters and reload the standard list.